# How to add data in sales order table after place order?

Tags: checkout, event-observer

In sales_flat_order i m adding custom column. Now when i place order that time i want to save data in custom column

I m trying this code:

config.xml

```
<global>
    <events>
         <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <price_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Company_Example_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setIdInOrder</method>
                </price_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
<global>
```

observer.php

```
public function setIdInOrder($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderId();
    $id = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getStudentId(); 
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $order->setData('student_id',$id);
    $order->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsStudentId();
}
```

set session like this

```
$id = 1;
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setStudentId($id);
```

Now i m getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in F:\wamp\www\tution\app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Observer.php on line 46

I can't get it where i m wrong. After Add this event this error occured. How to fixed this error

Comment: Even after you commented this event observer in config.xml, you face the same issue

Comment: Nope i try this comment event observer in config.xml than there is no error occured

Comment: you can try sales_order_place_after event

Comment: @saravanavelu not working

Comment: its working change in observer.php

Comment: Did you added the extra column to sales_flat_order? If no then you need to do this, otherwise when you do $order->setStudentId($id); there is no column to set this data

Comment: yes i m added extra column. In  my question i mention it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In config.xml add the event `sales_order_place_after`

Change in observer.php,it worked for me

```
public function placeAfter($observer)
{
    $id = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getStudentId(); 
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    $order->setStudentId($id);
    $order->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In config.xml change event replace this `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` with `sales_order_place_after`

Change in observer.php

```
public function setIdInOrder($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    $id = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getStudentId(); 

    $order->setStudentId($id);
}
```